# Python: extracting patterns from CSV

Tags: python, csv

Below is a sample of the typical contents of a CSV file.

```
['**05:32:55PM**', '', '', 'Event Description', '0', "89.0        near Some Street; Suburb Ext 3; in Town Park; [**Long 37\xb0 14' 34.8 E Lat 29\xb0", '']
['', '', '', '', '', "17' 29.1 S** ]", '']
['06:09:11PM', '', '', 'Event Description', '0', "89.0        near Someother Street; Suburb Ext 3; in Town Park; [Long 37\xb0 14' 34.9 E Lat 29\xb0", '']
['', '', '', '', '', "17' 29.1 S ]", '']
['Report Line Header                                                                                                                                ', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['HeaderX', ': HeaderY', '', 'HeaderZ', '', 'HeaderAA', '']
['From Date', ': 2014/01/17 06:00:00 AM', '', 'To Date   : 2014/01/17 06:15:36 PM', '', 'HeaderBB', '']
['HeaderA', 'HeaderB', 'Header0', 'Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3', '']
['', '', '', '', 'Header 4', 'Header5', '']
```

From each line containing the Date/Time and the location ( marked with ** -- ** ), I would like to just extract those relevant info, while ignoring the rest.

Even if I can just print results to screen, that is OK, ideally, create a new CSV containing only the time and lat/long.

Comment: This isn't really what your CSV file looks like, is it? Lines aren't really wrapped in brackets, and different rows don't contain completely different data, do they?

Comment: Is your issue that you want to know how to read a CSV file in Python, or you want to know how to parse the field values that are read in this particular case?

Comment: This is what I have tried already, ie, the extract is the result of this script, and without removing the [] etc
        `import csv


        csv_file_location ="CSV.csv"


        with open(csv_file_location,'r') as f:
 
            contents = csv.reader(f)
 
            for row in contents:
 
                content = str(row)
 
                #content = content.translate(None,'\\xb0, [, ] ')

                print content
`

Comment: Could you post a sample of the actual CSV file so we can see what the actual format is.

Comment: Sorry, cannot really post actual file - to further complicate it, the CSV file I have to work with is already a conversion from PDF to Excel, and then to CSV - nightmare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to extract the data of this file formatted as in your example, then you could use the following since the data in every line has a list representation:

```
>>> import ast
>>> f = open('data.txt', 'r')
>>> lines = f.readlines()
>>> for line in lines:
...     list_representation_of_line = ast.literal_eval(line)
...     for element in list_representation_of_line:
...             if element.startswith('**') and element.endswith('**'):
...                     print list_representation_of_line
...                     # or print single fields, e.g. timeIndex = 0 or another index
...                     # print list_representation_of_line[timeindex]
...                     break
...
['**05:32:55PM**', '', '', 'Event Description', '0', "89.0        near Some Street; Suburb Ext 3; in Town Park; [**Long 37\xb0 14' 34.8 E Lat 29\xb0", '']
>>>
```

otherwise you should reformat your data as csv

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion:
1. is "ast" a standard/free library?
2. I added the ** into the example to indicate what I am interested in. If there is a way to "detect" a proper timestamp entry, so that I can detect the time in what is usually the first element of lines ( but not on all lines ), then I could still use your example, since   I could use the "startswith LONG" to detect the lat/long section.

Comment: 1. ast is standard. 2. you could `try`(!) if the element/string can be converted to an instance of datetime (`from datetime import datetime`) as follows
`isinstance(datetime.strptime('2014/12/31', '%Y/%m/%d'), datetime)`. Please modify the pattern `%Y/%m/%d`to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use your script, but it fails at the first attempt to match an element - one of the lines that only has a "Report Header" seems to break the script.

Comment: Did you enclose the call to `strptime` in a `try: ... except:`?

Comment: Did this answered your original question? If yes, you might mark the question as answered. If you have furhter questions you should better post a new one instead of extending this one.

Comment: Hi
I did not even try to use the timestamp yet, I just modified your original code to detect the "PM/AM" on the time and the "LONG" in the lat long section - it already gave an error just trying that.

Comment: @Monty well, in your initial question you didn't ask for timestamps. Your question just mentioned elements marked with double asterisks

Comment: Yes, sorry, I may have been a bit clearer with the markings - tried to highlight, but since it was a code block, I could not use other markups, that's why you will see the second line in the original post does not have the **...

Answer (score -1):

If that's really what your CSV file looks like, I wouldn't even bother. It's got different data on different rows, and a huge mess of nested ad-hoc strings, with separators within separators.

Even once you get to your lat and long figures, they look like a bizarre mix of decimal, hex and character data.

I think you'd be asking for trouble by giving the impression that you can deal with data in that format programmatically. If it's just a once off task, and that's the extent of the data, I'd do it by hand.

If not, I think the correct solution is to push back and try to get some cleaner data.

Comment: I'm happy to cop a downvote, since I didn't answer the question. My advice was genuinely meant, though. I believe the real problem is not to parse the file, but to go back one step and get a clean file. I'd like to learn, here, though, so if this is a legitimate way for CSV to be structured, some clarification would be warmly received!

Comment: Perhaps the CSV format is a red herring here. The real issue is just to extract some information from general plain text?